# Expected value of a product of n random variables

Tags: statistics, expectation, products

I am currently dealing with an expression of the form

$\operatorname E[\Pi_{i=1}^n X_i]$,

where $\operatorname E$ represents the expectation value and $X_i$ is an arbitrary random variable. However, for $n>2$, I can not find *any* information about this specific expression anywhere.

So my question is: Does the general expectation value of a product of $n$ random variables have a specific name? And where can I find something about it in the literature? I emphasize that I am not particularly interested in the explicit calculation, which seems clear to me in principle, but would rather like to have some kind of reference.

**Remark:** I have found [this webpage](https://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/non-standard-covariance-stuff-involving-three-variables/), where a "three-way covariance" is introduced. A comment on this page refered to [coskewness](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50948/what-is-coskewness-and-how-can-it-be-calculated) as an implementation. However, I can not really establish a connection.

Comment: You neglect to specify whether the $X_i$ are independent or dependent ... and if the latter, the nature of the dependency. If they are mutually stochastically independent, then the expectation of the product is equal to the product of the expectations ... and there is not much more to say. .... ALSO, if your $X_i$ denote different random variables (rather than different values of a sample) then the expectation you consider is a simple case of what is known as a _product moment_.